# Background position fixed regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, background, position

I have two images on the background of the website I am working on, now for me on a 15" screen the position of these look fine, just behind and right/left of the content container. But on a big widescreen (or just other much larger screen sizes than mine) they end up being further away from the content container and look like they are on their own.

They are percentage based but, 25% from the left/right on my screen is different to someone with a widescreen. I need them in the same position regardless. X% from the center is probably more like it. Anyone know a suitable option? I've attached some code of what the images are using right now.

http://bit.ly/1aNgkfa

CSS for the background image of the herbs on the homepage (top-left)

```
.herb-bg-img {
margin-left: -15%;
margin-top: 5%;
position: absolute;
float: left;
z-index: -2;
}
```

CSS for the background image of the peppers on the homepage (bottom-right)

```
.peppers-bg-img-index {
float: right;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -30%;
margin-left: 880px;
z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `left` property along with a minus `margin-left` to align as needed:

```
.herb-bg-img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -600px; // Change as needed
    margin-top: 5%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Same with the right-hand image, only use a positive `margin-left` instead.

This should stay the same regardless of screen width.

Answer (score 0):

You're positioning these two images absolutely. They should be absolutely positioned in relation to a parent element with `position: relative`, however. Right now they are in relation to the page, which will continue to cause you problems.

I'd recommend adding `position: relative` to your `.container` elements.